# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '213894' for key 'PRIMARY

Tags: magento-1.9, exception

The magento works fine, and suddently starts giving an exception. The report says:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:96:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '213894' for key 'PRIMARY'";i:1;s:2966:"#0 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#4 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#5 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ma...', Array)
#6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(154): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('mage_log_visito...', Array)
#7 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Resource/Visitor.php(108): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_saveVisitorInfo(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(458): Mage_Log_Model_Resource_Visitor->_afterSave(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(167): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1303): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1284): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#13 /public_html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#14 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(505): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#15 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(59): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#16 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(409): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#17 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#18 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /public_html/app/Mage.php(639): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /public_html/index.php(98): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:37:"/illustrator-men-business-attire.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

**The last line (22) is changing with different URLs in the different report files.**

I have managed to get the website by restoring the database from the backup of 2 days ago. But after a few hours the same error appears.

Comment: Great hint from Dominic Xigen, that pointed me t the right database table. I have truncated the Magento database table log_visitor and the website started working again.

Comment: Glad it helped you. Please can you mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be taking issue with the visitor log mechanism.  Apologies you haven't said which version you are running.

You have a lot of options with regards to logging in M1.

You can disable a lot with this option.

https://bobcares.com/blog/magento-disable-visitor-log/

Not directly solving the problem though.  Just offering a work-around solution to this particular error.